# How to deprecate a private github package version

Tags: github, npm

I have a private github package with mutliple versions and I want to add deprecate notice to older versions. I tried with below npm commands does not work

`npm deprecate --registry https://npm.pkg.github.com/privateregistry my-package@1.0.10 "This package is deprecated, Please use latest version"`

but i get the below error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/privateregistry/my-package?write=true - Package [my-package] was not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'my-package@1.0.10' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Comment: Were you able to figure out an answer to this, @code? I see the same issue but there is no help online :(

Comment: Not yet... using some workarounds like adding change log

Answer (score -1):

Visit `https://www.npmjs.com/package/PACKAGE_NAME/access` and at the end of the page there's a "Deprecate package" button. It doesn't seem to allow entering a custom deprecation message however.