# How to deprecate an npm package published to the GitHub package registry?

Tags: npm, github-package-registry

I have a private package published to the GitHub package registry. I now want to *deprecate* it. I tried running this..

```
npm deprecate --verbose @test-engineering/test-roles "This package has been deprecated and superseded by @test-engineering/test-r - github.com/test-engineering/test-common/blob/master/packages/test"
```

and got this error..

```
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [
npm verb cli   '/tests/**/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node',
npm verb cli   '/tests/**/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/npm',
npm verb cli   'deprecate',
npm verb cli   '--verbose',
npm verb cli   '@test-engineering/test-roles',
npm verb cli   'This package has been deprecated and superseded by @test-engineering/test - github.com/test-engineering/test-common/blob/master/packages/test'
npm verb cli ]
npm info using npm@6.14.10
npm info using node@v12.20.1
npm verb npm-session da92d8e02740777e
npm http fetch GET 200 npm.pkg.github.com/test-engineering/@test-engineering%2ftest-roles?write=true 277ms
npm http fetch PUT 400 npm.pkg.github.com/test-engineering/@test-engineering%2ftest-roles 269ms
npm verb stack Error: 400 Bad Request - PUT npm.pkg.github.com/test-engineering/@test-engineering%2ftest-roles - failed to stream package from json: unhandled input: No new versions found in package.json
npm verb stack     at /tests/**/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-fetch/check-response.js:117:15
npm verb stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
npm verb statusCode 400
npm verb pkgid @test-engineering/test-roles@latest
npm verb cwd /tests/**/repos/test-common
npm verb Darwin 20.2.0
npm verb argv "/tests/**/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/node" "/tests/**/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.1/bin/npm" "deprecate" "--verbose" "@test-engineering/test-roles" "This package has been deprecated and superseded by @test-engineering/test - https://github.com/test-engineering/test-common/blob/master/packages/test"
npm verb node v12.20.1
npm verb npm  v6.14.10
npm ERR! code E400
npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT npm.pkg.github.com/test-engineering/@test-engineering%2ftest-roles - failed to stream package from json: unhandled input: No new versions found in package.json
npm verb exit [ 1, true ]
npm timing npm Completed in 824ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /tests/**/.npm/_logs/2021-03-31T06_11_49_149Z-debug.log
```

I wonder if its a scoped modules issue. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be going on? [I saw this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63700971/how-to-deprecate-a-private-github-package-version), but it looks like a different error than mine.

#### Edit 1

Some observations after setting up publishConfig correctly --

- I still end up with this error:

```
npm ERR! 
code E400 npm ERR! 400 Bad Request - PUT https://npm.pkg.github.com/test-engineering/@test-engineering%2ftest-roles - failed to stream package from json: unhandled input: No new versions found in package.json..
```

- Does it matter if repository#url is ssh instead of https? This is also a monorepo, so the repository field looks like this.. I wonder if this is also causing a problem.

```
{ 
  "type": "git", 
  "url": "ssh://git@github.com:test-engineering/test-common.git", 
  "directory": "packages/test-roles"
  }
```

- Does it matter where I run the `deprecate` command from? Should I be in the package directory?

Comment: Hey @krishwader did you find a fix for it?

Comment: I did not, sadly. its still broken :(

Comment: Could you not pass `--registry` to the `npm deprecate` command?

Answer (score 0):

Try to Specify the **publishConfig** option in `package.json` if you have not already set it up or look that it is set up right:

```
"publishConfig": {
    "registry":"https://npm.pkg.github.com/OWNER"
},
```

replace `OWNER` with the name of your user account on **GitHub** where you did publish the package.

**Example in package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "@Owner/repository",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/Owner/repository"
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "https://npm.pkg.github.com/Owner"
  }
}
```

The **Owner**, **repository/url** and the **publishConfig/registry** must match. `repository` is where you have your package. Hope this was of any help.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I now see a different error, which I've updated in the question..